# how to properly install joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I want to try joomla, but I can't even install it properly.
The last step I was able to make, using the manual installation is before the step before the finish. When I click next, I get this:
[image]

The database is created, when I check on phpmyadmin.
What's wrong, I think I have followed all the steps correctly because there's no error in every step. And my php settings is set to the recommended settings by joomla.

Comment: does "localhost" work normally? or rather, can you use PHP scripts etc offline and it's just a Joomla specific problem

Comment: yup it works normally , I just don't know why it returns this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server check list to make sure your Joomla installation will work OK :

- PHP version > 5.0
- Apache version > 2.0
- MySQL > 5.0
- Configuration file "configuration.php" permission is set to 777 (writable)

Are you sure you uploaded all the files?

This should work ... I think there's something wrong with your server configuration not Joomla. Try installing [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com) It's free host comes with Apache, PHP and MySQL. An easy installation without the hassle to configure it.

Comment: yup, I'm using wamp, I even changed the php settings just to match the recommended settings of joomla

Comment: the php, mysql and apache versions are slightly higher. Do I need to download and install a lower version

Comment: Make sure you install PHP version 5.2.x

Comment: You can download the 5.2.11 package here http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wampserver/WampServer2-PHP5211.exe?download and switch to it through WAMP icon on the system tray (beside the clock) If all fails, reinstall WAMP

Comment: I guess I have messed up with the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers hide the actual error messages returned by the server. In your case, you are probably getting `Error 500: Server Error`. You can find the details in the web server error log. The location of the log varies depending on the software and platform. Apache on Windows tends to put them under `%ProgramFiles%\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If the database and tables are created then installation is done. Remove the folder called `installation` and go to `http://localhost/joomla/` and it should work.